# Tensorflow 2.0 on Windows (SSE2): How do you stop 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.' when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, pip, conda, tensorflow2.0

**System Information:**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.4 and 3.7.0 <- default version
- Tensorflow 1.11.0
- Conda 4.7.12
- pip 19.3.1

I was trying to get Tensorflow 2.0 running on Windows 10, but my computer doesn't support the AVX/AVX2 instruction set, so I used a [wheel supporting SSE2](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.0.0/py37/CPU/sse2) instead, which I installed with pip.

I then procceded to attempting to run the python code from the [MINST Basic classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) tutorial from Tensorflow's official website:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)
```

Whem I tried to run the file, I was given this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This was the whole error, though (intro.py is the name of the file):

```
(base) C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NN\TF\Intro>python intro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tried and gotten the exsct same error on:

- pip
- anaconda (miniconda) both in and out of an environment

I do not have Cuda or cudNN as I have a crappy CPU and an on-board intel GPU, meaning I can't use tensorflow-gpu. I have also tried all the aforementioned options on both Python 3.6.4 and Python 3.7.0 to no avail. i would use an official version, but I have no devices that support AVX/AVX2. If I can't fix the issue, I will try on Linux (I have already tried, though, and gave up) or downgrading to a version which supports SSE2.

Comment: Do you use conda env or some virtualenv? Where you installed the wheels, to root python or env python?

Comment: I used conda env and installed the wheels on root python, uninstalled it, and then installed onto env python. Both didn't work.

Comment: I don't have any clue, I advice you to try dropping an issue on tensorflow github or try downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by installing https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe instead of  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587. May needed a newer Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable?

If you have another questions, Ask https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/issues.

Tensorflow 2.0 working on my pentium n4200 by using https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.0.0/py37/CPU/sse2.

It might be better to uninstall tensorflow1.11.0 and then install tensorflow2.0(SSE2)

I'm using Vanilla python(python.org) environment, not anaconda's.

Comment: why would the issue be resolved by installing https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe ? it is not clear to me why i need to install Microsoft c++?